# Mac app created with Unity submitted to AppStore always reject because it can't be launched

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

I create an Unity app to desktop platforms using Unity 2017.4.40. I publish it on Steam and now I Wana publish it on Mac app store. I follow this guide "https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-PortToAppleMacStore.html" to learn how to submit an Unity game to Mac App Store.

I do all steps on this guide and submit a PKG file to AppStore, but the game was rejected. I receive the following feedback from AppStore Review Team.

---

Hello,

The issues we previously identified still need your attention before we can approve your submission.

If you have any questions, we are here to help. Reply to this message in App Store Connect and let us know.

Guideline 2.1 - Performance

We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on Mac running macOS 12.3.

Specifically, the app did not launched and remained on a loading loop.

We tried to launch and review the app at the following two devices:

- MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)
- MacBook Air (M1, 2020)

Next Steps

Please run your app on a device to identify the issue(s), then revise and resubmit your app for review.

If you are unable to reproduce this issue, ensure you are testing the exact version of the app that you submitted for review, and that you're doing so in a minimally privileged environment. See Technical Q&A QA1778: How to reproduce bugs reported against Mac App Store submissions.

### For additional information on crash reports, see Diagnosing Issues Using Crash Reports and Device Logs.

I test my game on MacOS Big Sur 11.6.1 and on a fresh install on another device with MacOS Monterey 12.3.

For me it works perfectly in both tests. But when submitted to AppStore I got this error, now I don't know what I can do fix this to make my Unity game runs on MacOS devices from Apple review team.

How can I fix that?

Comment: I take it they didn’t provide any crash reports or device logs with the rejection? Is your loading time long enough that a particularly impatient reviewer might have given up waiting and marked it as a loading loop? Maybe if you could find some Mac owners (e.g. by requesting testers in your game’s Steam news or similar) who’d be willing to try the application and collect logs if it failed?

Comment: No crash log is provided. The loading time is instantaneous. I thought that was a good idea to try to search for testers on Steam. But I don't know how to enable testers to collect logs about the game.  How can I do that?

Comment: Possibly the [Diagnosing Issues Using Crash Reports and Device Logs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-issues-using-crash-reports-and-device-logs) page the review team refers to would help?

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for me because this information in the link is valid only for apps created with Xcode. In my case I didn't use Xcode, I use Unity Engine. Unity Engine doesn't create xcode project when Mac apps are created, Unity Engine only create xcode project for ios projects

Comment: If you export a Development build, [Unity log files](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html) should show up in the ~/Library/Logs/Company Name/Product Name/Player.log  directory.

Comment: I will try to create a new MacOs Monterey machine using VMWare and test my game

Comment: I sent the app for my friend who owns a Mac and she test it and didint work. After that, I try again and I was able to notarize my app and sent it again to my friend. She test and it works. I was able to Distribute my app outside AppStore.

Comment: Still trying to submit a version to MacAppStore.

Comment: So the problem seems to have been that apps need to be submitted to Apple’s notary service before they can be submitted to their App Store?

Comment: No. I understand now. Notarize an app is only necessary when you wanna send the directly to some person or publish it outside Mac App Store.

Comment: What did the actual problem turn out to be then?

Comment: The problem is that I don't fully understand how the process to submit a Mac app to the Mac App Store works. I thought I understand the entire process now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeed to publish one app in the Mac App Store.

I use the link below and I was able to understand how to publish my app in the Mac App Store

```
https://github.com/dilmerv/UnityBuildTools
```

My problem is that I forgot to sign my app with the "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: My Name (XXXXXXXXXX)" certificate and after that create a pkg file and sign it with "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: My Name (XXXXXXXXX)" certificate.

It works for me, my app was finally published in the Mac App Store.

There is another certificates that are needed to distribute the app outside Mac App Store. For me I will need to use the "Developer ID Application: My Name (XXXXXXXXXX)" to sign my app to distribute using Steam.